# Formatted a drive that has an OS installed, now my PC doesn't get past the BIOS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have 2 SSD's. One has Ubuntu installed, the other has Windows 7. They're separate drives, not just one drive partitioned into two if that matters.

I tried to install the official Nvidia display drivers the other day, but I was unsuccessful and kind of bricked my install.

I just booted into Windows and formatted the SSD which has Linux, and I was going to reinstall it. Reboot my PC with a bootable flash drive (the one I used to make the install the first time) and it can't display anything. I just get a black screen.

If I take out the flash drive and boot, it goes into "grub rescue mode", no idea what this is.

I set the SSD with Windows installed to be the first disk to boot from in the BIOS instead of the Linux one but I still cannot boot.

What can I do?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sorry, I forgot to change my Stack Exchange app on my phone to SuperUser

Comment: If you are sure that it's BIOS instead of UEFI, then you need to rewrite the MBR on the SSD with `bootsect` or `bootrec` (by booting a Windows installation ISO or so).

Comment: Shouldn't have suggested `bootrec` btw, since unlike `bootsect` you can't specify which disk to fix, and it will fix only the first disk.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my Windows disc and boot from that and fix Windows at least, surprisingly using their auto detect & correct utility after I tried to fix the MBR manually.